# Weird Characters Received Using Python Logging Socket Handler

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python (2.7) and need to log messaged to a remote server. I'm using the logging.handlers library but the messages are coming over weird. For now I'm using the SocketServer code provided on the python documentation website.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

class TestMan():
    def __init__(self,xmlString):

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s : %(name)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')

        logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)s : %(name)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        socket = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',1030)
        socket.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        socket.setFormatter(formatter)

        log.addHandler(socket)
        log.info("Starting Test")
```

**Received the following (Can't paste text so took a screen shot)**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3nZD.png

Server Code:

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 1030

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: _"Received the following (Can't paste text so took a screen shot)"_ Maybe you should find a way to provide an hexdump of those data, in order to identify those "weird characters". If nothing else can do the trick, may I suggest a network packet analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q1.1) ?

Answer (score 0):

The data sent by SocketHandlers is pickled before being sent.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SocketHandler

> emit() Pickles the record’s attribute dictionary and writes it to the
>   socket in binary format. If there is an error with the socket,
>   silently drops the packet. If the connection was previously lost,
>   re-establishes the connection. To unpickle the record at the receiving
>   end into a LogRecord, use the makeLogRecord() function.